# Where is the list of banality ratings for "Changeling: the Dreaming"?

Tags: world-of-darkness, changeling-the-dreaming

One of the rulebooks for *Changeling: the Dreaming* (a game in the old World of Darkness setting) has a list of banality ratings for the other WoD races, both supernatural and non-supernatural. Which rulebook is that list in, and which page is it on?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

http://www.vegasinshadow.triumphdelayed.com/banality.htm

There's an average banality score based on a character's type (mage, vampire, etc) in the core rulebook (p 287) and another table specifically for mages (p 281) which are recreated below.

- children 3-5
- wraiths 4
- drunks 5
- lunatics 5
- mages 5-7
- Malkavian & Ravnos vampires 5-6
- humans 6-7
- werewolves 7
- wyrm creatures 7
- mummies 8
- all other vampires 8-9
- Technocracy mages 8-10

Comment: You're my friggin' hero! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

There is more talk about banality and averages in both 'the Storytellers handbook' and 'Dreams and Nightmares'. the latter is considered the final word on such things.